# Convert hexadecimal value (ASCII) to text

Tags: c, ascii

I am trying to convert **ASCII** hexadecimal value (0x61 or 61) to it's `char` value (61 = a, etc..) **without** `atoi`, `scanf`, `strcat`.

I am saving `getchar()` to temp variable, then I save first one (6) in array, then save second one (1) in array, now i want take these two and convert them to their ASCII value.

```
68656c6c6f0d0a = hello

void asd(char fde)
{
    char asmg[3];
    asmg[0] = "0x";
    asmg[1] = "6";
    asmg[2] = "1";
    printf("%c", asmg);
}
```

I expected it to print "a", but it doesn't work.

Something like that, but this doesn't work. I need to put asmg[0], [1], [2] to one char, then it should work.
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to use any of the library functions? Because those were designed specifically for that task. If you want to learn the concept behind it, I suggest looking at some C library's source code (e.g. glibc).

Comment: Think about what hexadecimal means.  What does the character '6' mean for the value of the byte you're trying to extract?  How is that different from the the '1'?  What's the pattern?

Comment: `printf("%c\n", (char) strtol(fgets((char[6]){0}, 6, stdin), NULL, 16))`?

Comment: Your vocabulary is a bit off.  You want to convert a hexadecimal string "616865..." to ASCII characters, where the character represented by 0x61 is 'a'.  That's why `scanf` and `atoi` are forbidden in your assignment.  You're trying to do string to number conversion, and it just happens the resulting number represents a character.

Comment: @alk nice 1-liner that meets the goal, except code needs at least 7 than 6 to read the whole line `"hello\n"`.

Comment: Better to post the code that does "I am saving getchar() to temp variable, then I save first one (6) in array, then save second one (1) in array,..." than just describe it.

Comment: @chux: Thx, I had `"0x61\n"` in mind as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do but this may help.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int hex[6] = {0x68, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F};
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <6; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", hex[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, this helped me a lot, but i am reading by one char.
I mean, first getchar() gives me 6, second getchar gives me 8, now i need to put prefix 0x,
char something[] = {"0x", "6", "8"}; and now i need to print it as a "h"

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to convert Hexastring to ASCII

```
void hexToAscii(unsigned char *buf, int size, char *str) {
int i;

for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    sprintf(str + (i * 2), "%02X", buf[i]);
 }
}
```

Don't for get to set the last element on the string  to null.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char hex[] = "68656c6c6f0d0a";
    char text[(sizeof(hex)+1)/2];

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(hex[i]){
        int up = '0' <= hex[i] && hex[i] <= '9' ? hex[i] - '0' : hex[i] - 'a' + 10;//lowcase
        if(hex[++i] == '\0'){
            printf("invalid format\n");
            return -1;
        }
        int low = '0' <= hex[i] && hex[i] <= '9' ? hex[i] - '0' : hex[i] - 'a' + 10;//lowcase
        text[j++] = up * 16 + low;
        ++i;
    }
    text[j] = 0;
    printf("%s", text);

    return 0;
}
```